# Email is None(while fetching user data) for some cases while using microsoft graph api

Tags: python, django, microsoft-graph-api

I know I can fetch the details using url `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/` . When I use my personal outlook mail, it actually says

```
[{'displayName': 'vineeth sagar', 
  'surname': 'sagar', 'givenName': 'vineeth', 
   'userPrincipalName': 'MYACTUALEMAIL REMOVED FOR PRIVACY',
   'businessPhones': [], 'jobTitle': None, 
   'mail': None, 'mobilePhone': None, 
   'officeLocation': None, 'preferredLanguage': None}]
```

My email is indeed correct but why was it given in userPrinciplName.
Also when trying to While I tried it with a couple of other accounts, which were actually registered with office 365(Mine was not),I get the mail with their actual email. Why is this not consistent? What mistake have I done? I registered my mobile number while registering my personal email. So why is my mobile field also None. I am using OAuth for the first time, but I know that there is nothing wrong with Oauth because every other functionality I want works(Like sending mails,fetching mails) etc. English is not my first language, so please forgive me if I have made some mistakes. If you want any clarifications please ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userPrincipalName` is the address used for authentication. The `mail` property is used to surfaces the mailbox name from Exchange. For personal Microsoft Accounts (MSA), the mailbox is owned by Outlook.com, not Exchange Online. As such, the `mail` property will be `null`.

The missing phones are a known issue. Technically this has to do with how Outlook.com/Hotmail stored profile information. Currently, it isn't possible to access these values from Graph.

Comment: So if I got this right userPrincipleName can be used to store information about the person  that has given me tokens for their application? Thank you very much

Comment: You cannot edit the UPN, it is the name of the account. It is read-only.